# View not rendering properly when added to window in iOS 9

Tags: autolayout, ios9

I have a view (view 1) with another view (view 2). I am adding view 1 on UIWindow and everything was working as expected in iOS 8.
But in iOS 9, view 2 is not getting rendered properly, when view 1 is added on the window. I checked the frame of view 2, I am getting (0, -21, , ). So autolayout constraints are not getting added to view 2. I have attached an image link for the reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxioam78of1tyuv/stackoverFlow.png?dl=0

Comment: It would really help if you'd share your code + storyboard; will be much easier to help you

Comment: How are you adding view2 to the window? Is view generated via code, a xib, or storyboard? We need more information to go on!

Comment: View2 is xib added on window.

Comment: Solved it try adding it on window using appDelegate.window.rootviewcontroller.view